# What needs to be open to the Internet for Office 2019 applications run smoothly?

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking, microsoft-office

In a tightly closed down environment, I have a linux machine acting as router with a fireHOL firewall (iptables), limitting not only inbound traffic, but also outbound traffic.

Office 2019 applications running on windows 10, suffer from frequent hangs and freezing. We do not think this is related to bad installations (everything was tried already), but rather the firewall blocking lots of connections to the outside world.

FireHOL is far from convenient when it comes to logging. We see a lot of blocks, but cannot really  point the finger back to the office products or microsoft.

We would like to understand what needs to be whitelisted for Office 2019 products (Word, Outlook, Excel) to work without frequent freezing.

FireHOL does not do FQDN whitelisting directly, but needs a list of IP adresses to whitelist. Unfortunately, the iblocklist_org_microsoft (see http://iplists.firehol.org/?ipset=iblocklist_org_microsoft ) is way outdated (updated last 2017).

Question: What needs to be open from inside to outside for Office 2019 products working flawlessly?

Also, any hints on better troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Thanks for any pointer.

Dan

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: The link provided by joeqwerty has the answer to your question, but it's an administrative nightmare. I haven't had to do something like this for a few years now (thankfully), but when I did, even adding the ports and protocols dictated in the MS docs STILL gave issues with O365, Skype for Business, etc. Not only that, but MS can change those urls & IPs at will or when new products/features release. If you HAVE to do this, I would recommend getting a firewall with capability for one of those cloud service lists that will automatically maintain this for you and let you easily create policies.

Comment: have you tried to check Graphic card drivers? cause i faced the same thing and after installing both cpu and gpu drivers it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 URL and IP list

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide

If you use web filtering I have Sophos example

https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000038173?language=en_US#Method-1